# Spring, React Authorization request

Tags: reactjs, spring, axios, token

I have a backend filter in my application that is responsible for handling the Authorization header and extracting the token from it. However, when making API requests from your React frontend, the token seems to be null on the server-side. I have verified that the token is being set correctly in the frontend and it is not null in Postman.

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ceqr.png) // it works

[in frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzwt3.png)   // Sending null and throwing 403

[Frontend Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lshu1.png). //Value from local storage returns as "token" so I ran replace all command

[Login Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48bEI.png) //i posted it so you have an idea about how i storage token

also the token is saved to the userToken(localstorage) and I can print that token value on the Mypage page

[Config Backend 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrJS6.png)  //Config Backend1

[Config Backend 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcIxN.png)

I would appreciate if you write the solution in detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.